# When creating database model edmx files, Visual Studio 2k10 doesn't list all stored procedures

Tags: sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm having a really hard time with Visual Studio 2010.  I have a SQL database I am programming against with Entity Framework.  Most of the SQL code is simply executing stored procedures, which Entity Framework excels at.

However, I'm having a problem.  When I click `Update Model From Database`, the Update Wizard intermittently fails to list all the stored procedures in the database.  I've created a stored procedure called `sp_foo`.  Sometimes, the Update Wizard will display and allow me to select it.  Sometimes, it behaves as if `sp_foo` does not exists.  I have absolutely no idea what is causing this.  I can always execute `sq_foo` in SQL Server Management Studio.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your permissions on the database to see EF can see all stored procs. 
I had a similar problem that I fixed that way.

You might have to run something like this.

If Exists (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'UserName' ) GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].storedProcName TO [YourUserName]

Comment: As a matter of fact, the problem did have to do with permissions.  The reason that the problem was intermittent was because I failed to specify the same uid and password for each SQL server connection.  All is explained.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin - I had exactly the case You described